# Shell Exec in Apache sends output to error log

Tags: php, apache

I need to run a script from a php script that is run in Apache webserver. I have tried both exec and shell_exec and both times the scripts runs just fine but the output goes to the error log (as if doing error_log($output)).

So my question is how can I capture the output in a variable and not have it be sent to the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `shell_exec` doesn't grab `stderr`, it only grabs `stdout`.

You will have to add `2>&1` at the end of your command to pipe `stderr` to `stdout`, then both will appear in the return string from `shell_exec`.

If you want to capture the file descriptors `stderr` and `stdout` separately, you can use `proc_open` [instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: Thank you!!!! This worked perfctly. It speaks really bad about the interpreter of the other script taht outputs NORMAL messages on the stderr. Its an R script.